# Joi alternative groups of keys in schema

Tags: validation, joi

In the schema below I want to require that it has either Lat/Lon or Northing/Easting keys. How to accomplish this and also add other optional keys to the schema after these? I looked at [xor](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#objectxorpeers) but that only seems to support individual keys, not sets of keys.

```
const schema = Joi.alternatives().try({
    Northing: Joi.string().required(),
    Easting: Joi.string().required(),
}, {
    Lat: Joi.string().required(),
    Lon: Joi.string().required(),
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I've found the solution:

```
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
  Northing: Joi.string(),
  Easting: Joi.string(),
  Lat: Joi.string().when('Northing', {
    is: Joi.string().required(),
    then: Joi.string(),
  }),
  Lon: Joi.string().when('Easting', {
    is: Joi.string().required(),
    then: Joi.string(),
  }),
}).xor('Northing', 'Lat').xor('Easting', 'Lon');
```